# Creating 2nd instance of IE

Tags: vba

I want to create 2nd instance of

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
```

in web scraping macro but don't want to open new internet explorer window.

when I use ie.navigate 2nd times without creating 2nd ie instance

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
```

it gives error

> Runtime Error '-2147024726 (800700aa)': Automation Error. The
> requested resource is in use

Please help
thank you!!

Comment: brax, any solution

Comment: Hello Anyone, please help me in this...